# Как ввести ограниченное число символов на Python и отсортировать их по возрастанию?

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать такую программу (не используя списки):
Вводим `N` - количество цифр, которые мы можем ввести:

```
n = int(input('Введите кол-во цифр '))
```

После этого надо сделать `x`, в которое мы можем ввести то `N` кол-во чисел в текстовом виде НЕ в цифровом!
Ну и мы получается вводим цифры и когда, например, мы ввели `5` и ввели `5` чисел, например, `5 2 4 7 6`, то больше не можем ввести. Потом нужно каждую цифру отсортировать от меньшего к большему и вывести итог. На Python

Вот что я пробовал:

```
i = 1 
k = 0 
p = 0 
n = int(input('Введите кол-во цифр: ')) 

for i in range(1, n+1): 
    a = int(input())
```

Comment: покажите пожалуйста, что вы уже пробовали сделать.

Comment: Пробовал сделать так:
i = 1
k = 0
p = 0
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
  a = int(input())
Это единсвенное что пришло мне в голову
но оно вводится получается если вводим 3 числа N,
и введём 2 3 1 то выведится и запомнится в переменную a последнее.
А мне надо в текст. виде в 1 переменную и как я написал в задаче

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = int(input('Введите кол-во цифр '))
print(*sorted(int(input()) for _ in range(n)))
```

Ну или можно в одну строчку

```
print(*sorted(int(input()) for _ in range(int(input('Введите кол-во цифр ')))))
```

Comment: тут не используются списки верно?

Comment: Нет, как видишь, тут нету инициализации списка и квадратных ковычек

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: а что делает * перед sorted ?

Comment: Отметь мой ответ галочкой, если не сложно

Comment: Распаковывает в обычный вид то, что мы отсортировали

Comment: Оk, написано надо подождать 3 минуты чтобы поставить галочку